# Spark .show()'s table is not aligned in Google Colab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I am testing Apache Spark command on Google Colabs, but the table that is printed out does not aligned. It looks fine on some machines, but not on some machines.

So I wonder if anyone could help clarify why does this happen. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spark has an option to show your dataframe on Jupyter Notebook like Pandas.

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled",True)
```

Your Dataframe will be shown as a HTML Table.

```py
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("sample.csv")
df.limit(10)
```